# file_get_contents() with different port in URL => returns boolean: false

Tags: json, file-get-contents

I'm trying to grab a json array from an URL that has some get variable parameters and runs from a different port - which is in the url.

```
$link = "https://web.xmrpool.eu:8119/stats_address?address={address}";
```

Tried it with curl already, but it keeps returning a boolean false.

Would appreciate the help.

merry x-mas J

Comment: `curl -k https://web.xmrpool.eu:8119/stats_address?address={address}` try this on your terminal and see whether it shows the output

Comment: It returns the json string perfectly. The first line is empty tho.

Comment: Note: the empty first line was empty in previous attempts so that's not a problem

Comment: https://pastebin.com/meRZJ8r2

Got this out of some debug information